# ANTLR No viable alternative at input query

Tags: antlr

I am designing a parser for a small language - the grammar I have is as follows:

```
grammar Test;

r : specification+;

specification : MODULE module_def EOF;

module_def : ID EQ classExp;

classExp : basicClassExp
         | altClassExp
         ;


basicClassExp : CLASS (classCode)* END;

altClassExp : ALTCLASS (classCode)* END;

classCode : 'classCode';

EXCLAMATION : '!';

EQ : '=';

MODULE : 'module';

END : 'end';

CLASS : 'class';

ALTCLASS : 'altclass';


ID
:   JavaLetter JavaLetterOrDigit*
;

fragment
JavaLetter
:   [a-zA-Z$_]
| ~[\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF]
|  [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
;

fragment
JavaLetterOrDigit
:   [a-zA-Z0-9$_]
| ~[\u0000-\u007F\uD800-\uDBFF]
|  [\uD800-\uDBFF] [\uDC00-\uDFFF]
;


WS  :  [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
;

COMMENT
:   '/*' .*? '*/' -> channel(HIDDEN)
;

LINE_COMMENT
:   '//' ~[\r\n]* -> channel(HIDDEN)
;
```

An example of correct code would be:

```
module T = class end
```

When I run it on the following code :

```
module ! T ! = !
    class !    
    end !
```

I expect it to report errors where the exclamation marks are. Instead I get:

```
line 1:7 extraneous input '!' expecting ID

line 1:11 extraneous input '!' expecting '='

line 1:15 no viable alternative at input '!'
```

When I remove the altClassExp rule alternative, it reports all errors i.e.

```
line 1:7 extraneous input '!' expecting ID

line 1:11 extraneous input '!' expecting '='

line 1:15 extraneous input '!' expecting 'class'

line 2:10 extraneous input '!' expecting {'classCode', 'end'}

line 3:6 extraneous input '!' expecting <EOF>
```

What do I need to change so I can keep my altClassExp rule and also report all the extraneous exclamation marks?

Thanks

Comment: Are you complaining that the parser doesn't flag every single non-conforming element in the input? That's a tall order, I think - input that doesn't adhere to the grammar can sometimes cause the parser to get confused so that it can't properly re-sync with valid input that follows.

Comment: Hi, I don't expect it to catch every error, it's just the the classExp rule in the code above represents a choice of the different classes a module could have, and for it to break down before it has even started to parse the code that represents a class is frustrating.